# How do you check if a property value is an array within an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

If we have:

```
var obj = {
  key: [1000, 10, 50, 10]
};
```

-If the array at the given key is empty, it should return 0.

-If the property at the given key is not an array, it should return 0.

-If there is no property at the given key, it should return 0.

I'm trying to get the average of the elements at the property (key) with a function, getAverageOfElementsAtProperty(obj, 'key').. I managed that part with exception of the 3 points above.

I tried this:

```
if (obj[key].constructor != Array || !obj.hasOwnProperty(key) || 
    obj[key] == []) {
    return 0;
}
```

But I'm unsure if using three or operational is the correct move...

Comment: Why you have to do three checks? Just checking if the key existed and the key is not an array is enough. Plus if the key is not defined this will throw an error because you're accessing the `constructor` property of a potentially not existing property.

Comment: Why not just use `Array.isArray(obj.key)` ?

Comment: @NewToJS the OP wants to check if the Array is not empty too (`Array.isArray([]) === true`).

Comment: if (!obj[key] || !Array.isArray(obj.key)) {
  return 0;
 }

That cleared things out guys, thanks. Just making sure i'm checking two conditions there, if the property exists and if it's an array. Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for each condition you mentioned it can be done as follows

> If the array at the given key is empty, it should return 0.
>   `obj.key.length === 0`
>
> If the property at the given key is not an array, it should return 0.
>   `!Array.isArray(obj[key])`
>
> If there is no property at the given key, it should return 0.
>   `!obj.hasOwnProperty("key")`.

You can directly check for a `falsy`  value to check the existence. Also, check if the the value is an array by using the `Array.isArray` function and then for checking the length of array, use the `length` property.

```
if(!obj.hasOwnProperty("key") || !Array.isArray(obj[key]) || obj.key.length === 0)){
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `!obj[key]` will fail if `obj[key] == false`. So it's not good practice to see if a property exist or not using that.

Comment: @Agalo what if someone uses an object to contain `false` or `null` as values then the user wants to check if some property exist or not. Then `!obj[key]` will exclude the properties that has the values `false` or `null`.

Comment: For the record, `!obj[key]` is not the best way to check if a property exists, indeed, as pointed by @ibrahimmahrir. Also, this check is irrelevant, because `Array.isArray()` can receive `undefined` and will return `false`.

Comment: @Agalo `obj.key` is the same as `obj["key"]`. It checks wether the key `"key"` exist or not. You should check if a key exist like this `obj[key] !== undefined`.

Comment: `hasOwnProperty()` and the `in` operator. would be better to check for existence of property.

Answer (score 2):

You can check multiple conditions like this

```
if ( 
    typeof obj === 'object' &&      // you have an object
    'key' in object &&              // it contains a "key"
    Array.isArray( obj['key'] )     // it is an array
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`if (obj[key].constructor != Array || ...` will throw an error if `obj[key]` is `undefined` because, then, you'll be accessing `constructor` of `undefined` which will throw an error. What you need to do is check if a the value `obj[key]` exist then if it is an array like this:

```
if(obj[key] !== undefined || obj[key].constructor != Array)
    return 0;
```

**In general:** The `or` (`||`) operator will stop checking (evaluating) after the first valid check. Consider `check0 || check1 || ... || checkN`, if `checki` is `true` then `checki+1 ... checkN` won't be evaluated at all. Because only one valid check is sufficient. Here is an example:

```js
var n = 5;
if(n == 5 || console.log("Here 1"))
  ;

n = 4;
if(n == 5 || console.log("Here 2"))
  ;
```

As you can see, `Here 1` is never loged because the code `console.log("Here 1")` is never reached.

Comment: Good catch, that totally slipped through me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I like to break up my `if` into the business logic that it needs to fulfill. I find it easier to understand when I get back to it later on. So I would do it this way

```
if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) return 0; // If there is no property at the given key
if (!Array.isArray(obj[key])) return 0; // If the property at the given key is not an array
if (obj[key].length === 0) return 0; // If the array at the given key is empty
// add this point we know there is a valid array
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check, first, **[1]** if the key exists, then **[2]** if it's array, and, then, **[3]** if it's not empty.

**Order matters**: due to [`Short-circuit evaluation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation), if it evaluates true in the first condition, it skips nexts checks (then, you can safely assume that the key exists, that it's an array and so on...)

```
var obj = {
  key: [1000, 10, 50, 10],
  key2: [],
  key3: "abc"
};


function isValid(obj, key) {
    if (
        (typeof obj[key] === 'undefined') || //If there is no property at the given key (first)
        (!Array.isArray(obj[key])) ||  //If the property at the given key is not an array (IE9>=)
        (obj[key].length == 0) //If the array at the given key is empty,
    ) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1; /* or whathever you want */
    }
}


console.log(isValid(obj, "key")); //1
console.log(isValid(obj, "key2")); //0
console.log(isValid(obj, "key3")); //0
console.log(isValid(obj, "key4")); //0
```

---

**Note** that `(typeof obj[key] === 'undefined')` is not necessary here, because `Array.isArray(undefined) === false` (check [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)), so, you can skip this check.

Comment: Thanks for explaining mrlew